# "wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 4)" error with std::map and typedef

Tags: c++, stdmap

Hi I want to create a typedef with a std::map, but the compiler is returning the following error: "erro: wrong number of template arguments (2, should be 4)"

Code:

```
typedef std::map<unsigned int, float> AcumulatorHash;
```

Comment: That should work fine.  std::map has four template arguments, but the last two have defaults.  What is the context of this typedef?

Comment: Does it work if you provide the other 2 arguments?

Comment: I think we need to see a bit more of the code.

Comment: Please provide a short, complete sample program that demonstrates the problem. See http://sscce.org for reasons why. In your case, I suspect that you will discover the problem in the process of creating the sample.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you don't provide a complete program, I have to use my psychic powers.

My crystal ball says that you need to add `#include <map>` to the beginning of your source code.

Comment: I suppose that could be the problem, but I'd expect a problem with the name `map` being unknown instead. (for the record - not the downvoter)

Comment: This causes a `map in namespace std does not name a type` erorr in GCC. How would it know the number of template arguments without the type declaration?

Comment: That solved the problem, Thanks.

The main problem was that the compiler error wasn't very usefull, but I thnik that's maybe I was including another kind of map from boost and the G++ went crazy .

Comment: My crystal ball says someone has had the same problem in the past. That was the fastest I've ever seen something go from -2 to +4.

Comment: Way to go from -2 -> 4 in one smooth step ;-)

Comment: Suppose some other header forward-declared the map template, but omitted the default template parameters: `template <class x, class y, class z, class q> class map;`  I think he'd get this error message.

Comment: @Robᵩ, that'd go well in the answer.

Comment: `<soapbox>`This is why we always need an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). It would've taken everyone 2 seconds to say "You need the map header."`</soapbox>`

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error. The problem was a period instead of a comma separating the template arguments.